# Get data from HTML table in python 3 using urllib and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have a HTML table in my disk. I want to use first urllib and then BeautifulSoup. However, I get an error. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request     
Data ="C:/Splits.html"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(splitData).read()
page=splitData
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

The Splits.html file looks like the following:

```
    A                   B      C       D
1 Company            Old FV  New FV  Split Date
2 Palred Tech          5       10    26-04-2016
3 ABM Knowledg        10       5     07-04-2016
```

and the error I get is the following:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1324, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: it appears you are calling `splitData` without a parameter or an object that it should be a function of

Comment: Shouldn't `splitData` be `Data`?...You don't need `urllib` since you're working with a local file, you can just open the file with beautifulSoup

Comment: Try using User Data ="file://C:/Splits.html"

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies. I used CyberDrone's tip and it worked, but it just needs to be "file:///C:/Splits.html", with three / instead of two.@ danidee, if you just go directly to BeautifulSoup it just parses the name of the file, not the file, at least on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

To read a local file, use `open()` and pass the file-object to `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
with open("path/to/file") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
```

Note that there is no need to actually read the file - `BeautifulSoup` would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

> To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You
>   can pass in a string or an open filehandle:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```